# Multicluster istio observability in Kiali dashboard

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, istio, kiali, istio-kiali

I have set up the [multi-primary helloworld example](https://istio.io/latest/docs/setup/install/multicluster/multi-primary/) on 2 GKE clusters in the same network. I have followed all the instructions on the Istio example page and I am able to [verify cross cluster traffic](https://istio.io/latest/docs/setup/install/multicluster/verify) in the command line.

However when I install and open the kiali dashboard from one cluster (say the one with helloworld-v1 installed) I am not able to open the workload details of helloworld-v2 (which is showing up in the application graph when creating traffic) and I get the following error

```
Workload.Kiali "helloworld-v2" not found
```

I want both v1 and v2 workloads to be accessible from either control plane. Where am I going wrong? how can I debug this?

Comment: I don't think it is possible to view remote traffic info (yet) : https://kiali.io/documentation/latest/features/#_graph_view_cluster_and_namespace_boxing

Comment: I have reached a similar conclusion. Thanks!